# Updating all values in a C# keyed collection in O(n) time?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

This is a problem I have encountered again and again in C#, but haven't found a general solution. In C++/STL, all values in a map can be updated in O(n) time using an iterator without using keys to access each element. Is there a way to obtain similar behavior with any of the C# collections such as SortedList, SortedDictionary?

I can do something like

```
foreach (int key in list.Keys)
{
    list[key] *= 3;
}
```

But that would take O(n * log(n)) as the searching each element using key takes log(n).

Just to give an idea, I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
SortedList<int, double> list = new SortedList<int,double>();

// Add few values fist

// E.g. first try ...
IList<double> values = list.Values;
for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    values[i] *= 3;
}

// E.g. second try
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, double> kv in list)
{
    kv.Value *= 3;
}
```

Since the List is already sorted it should be possible to traverse it updating values (not keys) at the same time. It doesn't look like there is a problem with that from the implementation point of view, but for some reason the functionality is not made available it seems.

Also this is not a trivial case as the same method can be used to iterate from a known position to another modifying values in that range.

Is there a way to do this in C# with any of the keyed collections in .NET without using 3rd party libraries?

Thank you

Jeeves

Comment: So why isnt your second try code valid?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your code is valid, you are answering your own question... or maybe I'm loosing something big...

Comment: Your second try is doing the Job. What are you asking?

Comment: his second try isn't valid because you can't set the .Value property -- it is readonly

Comment: I don't quite see why you eschew O(n log n) -- if n is large enough for the `log n` factor to matter, the `n` factor is already so huge that it ought to be worth looking into ways of avoiding the whole-collection update altogether (e.g. a collection-level scaling factor which you apply on lookup and retrieval).

Comment: The question mentions 'any keyed collection' so there is no way of knowing if a particular collection actually uses good enough algorithm for retrieving the value by key.

Comment: - Martin is right on the 'Value' property of KeyValuePair being readonly.

Comment: - delnan, thanks for the hint. In my case the a single value could be updated in between scaling. Agree that I could still follow that method by keeping extra information such as dirty bits. In fact the problem is a bit more complex, but I reduced it to a general problem that I encounter again and again, perhaps because I have been using stl maps. For the data set I am working with, 10^10, the time difference is about 10 fold.

Comment: - Knaģis, Agree that with a HashTable etc the access time is different and also iterating in sorted order without using keys is not possible as in the case of SortedList and SortedDictionary. I was thinking mainly of the latter two.

Comment: The original code in my example, the n * log(n) version, doesn't work either. "Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated." error. So it looks like 'values' cannot be modified during enumeration at all. Creating a copy of at least the indices or wrapping the value type are the only options it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to wrap the value in a reference type.

```
class WrappedInt { public int Value; }
Dictionary<TKey, WrappedInt> dictionary = ...;
foreach (var wrappedVal in dictionary.Values)
{
    wrappedVal.Value *= 3;
}
// or 
foreach (var wrappedVal in dictionary)
{
    wrappedVal.Value.Value *= 3;
}
```

This approach would work with any collection (list or dictionary). One of the few collections that does this by design without the wrapper is `LinkedList`.

Of course, if you have a very specific collection (created by some external component), you can always fall back to using reflection and change the values directly in the underlying storage.

Comment: Thanks. From all the answers it appears that there is no collection that allow what I want, but this seem to be the least costly solution.

Comment: This work with SortedList as well. Still I am puzzled why direct modification is not allowed during list traversal. Perhaps because the iteration variable / Values list needs to be readonly and it has nothing to do with the collection type.

Comment: The problem is that you iterate over collection where the value is a value-type, not reference type. So the runtime copies the actual integer into new location in memory when you iterate through it - even if you would be able to replace the integer, you would replace it in the new location, not the place where it is stored originally in the collection.
The same reason is why you can't replace the whole instance of a reference type (just the propreties) - the pointer is copied when returned from the iterator.

Comment: I think it boils down to this: All the approaches we have tried so far depend on IEnumerator and IEnumerator.Current property is readonly. No setter, only a getter. If I am right, that is the only iterator there is. There is no iterator that provides a setter. If there was, list.Values could have implemented that. I was thinking that there shouldn’t be any restriction to provide that access from the data structure POV, but didn’t realize that the only way to iterate is through IEnumerable. On the other hand, indexers provide read-write access to values.

Answer (score 2):

```
SortedList<int, double> list = new SortedList<int,double>
{
    { 1, 3.14 },
    { 2, 1.618 },
};

var newList = new SortedList<int, double>(list.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value * 3)).Dump();
```

The SortedList constructor is O(n) according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/016ae4ba.aspx).
The .ToDictionary loops over Dictionary.Add under the hood.  Dictionary.Add is O(1) when the capacity is sufficient [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx)

O(n) * O(1) is still O(n) so you're good :-)

The space requirements are of course doubled using this approach.

Comment: Thanks, it is a clever answer! Yes, space requirement and the increase in the constant factor might push the crossover point with n * log(n) solution beyond my sample size.
What I really wanted to know were
a) if there is any keyed collection that allows this
b) if not, is there is a logical reason apart from 'it is by design' type answer. I mean, foreach allows to traverse the SortedList in O(n), so why not allow modification of values.

Answer (score 0):

In C# accessing a Dictionary element is close to constant time of O(1).

You can get a list of values by calling Dictionary.Values and updating them:

```
foreach(var value in valuesDict.Values)
{
    // update value;
}
```

Getting the value of this property (`Dictionary.Values`) is [also an O(1) operation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not O(1) in case of many hash collisions - though that most probbably will only apply if the key has a bad GetHashCode implementation or for crafted attacks.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that this doesn't work when TValue is a value type because 'var value' is a copy.